# #ifdef inside a macro call works with gcc but not with msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, macros, variadic-macros

I am have a macro TYPELIST which takes variadic arguments. I want to have something like

```
typedef TYPELIST(A
                ,B
                ,C
                ,D
#ifdef BLA_
                ,E
#endif
                ,F)
```

This works perfectly with gcc. However, when I try to compile it with MSVC it parses ifdef and endif as macro arguments. I know one way would be to put the macro call inside an ifdef. However, if I have a huge list and if I want to include different classes depending on different macros defined, it would become tedious. Is there a particular reason why this works in gcc and not with MSVC?

Comment: Yes, it's not legal C++ to place preprocessor directives in a macro call. Compilers can do what they like if you attempt that. As you can see g++ and MSVC do different things.

Comment: @john, shouldn't your comment better be an answer?

Comment: Which versions of GCC and MSVC?

Comment: @AdriC.S. It's an answer to his question, but not really an answer to his problem. Maybe someone else can suggest a workable solution.

Comment: gcc-4.7 and cl-16.00.30319.01

Comment: Is it possible to force the compiler to preprocess the ifdef block before making the macro call. I know pragma will ensure this but I am not sure how do I get about this using pragma.

Comment: can you create a real example?

Answer (score 1):

Using #ifdef inside a macro isn't legal. I am sort of surprised that gcc allows this. I'm afraid you have to put the #ifdef around the entire definition, i.e.

```
#ifdef BLA_
    typedef TYPELIST(a,b,c,d,e,f)
#else
    typedef TYPELIST(a,b,c,d,f)
#endif
```

Comment: It's not illegal in the sense of ill-formed, it just has undefined behaviour. So gcc can accept it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard (§16.3.4/3), "The resulting completely
macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as
a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one,[...]".  If
g++ processes the `#ifdef/#endif` here, it's an error in the
compiler (at least if you've requested standards conformance,
e.g. with `-std=...`).

Comment: But it works with g++ and clang++. I also tried to force standard conformance using `-std=c++03` but it still doesn't complain.

Comment: Actually, it's not an error, it's just UB. 16.3/11 (talking about arguments to a function-like macro): "If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Ah yes.  There is a difference between "expanding to a preprocessor directive" and preprocessing tokens in an argument list.  So it's not an error as far as the standard is concerned; just a poor choice of how they handle undefined behavior (although instead of a choice, it may be related to how they tokenize).